# How to get ACL to allow group to have permission to folder

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, group-policy, acl

I'm a little confused on how to get this working.

I have ACL working and I need to create two goups:

- github-total: group that the users in that group have permissions to the folder "/var/git" to read/write/execute.
- github-read: group that the users in that group have permissions to the folder "/var/git" to read.

For the group "github-total" I have done the following:

As "git" user:

```
$ cd /var
$ mkdir github
$ chmod 770 github
$ ls -al
drwxrwx---+  3 git git   4096 Oct  4 21:48 github


# useradd andre -m
# passwd andre
# groupadd github-total
# usermod -a -G github-total andre
# id andre
uid=500(andre) gid=500(andre) groups=500(andre),502(github-total) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
# cd /var
# setfacl -R -m group:github-total:rwx github
# setfacl -R -d -m group:github-total:rwx github
# getfacl github
file: github
owner: git
group: git
user::rwx
user:git:rwx
group::rwx
group:git:rwx
group:github-total:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:github-total:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

Unfortunately this is not working for me, with user "andre", I cannot list "/var/github"

```
$ cd /var/github
bash: cd: /var/github: Permission denied
```

How can I list this folder adding a group to the ACL?

Best Regards,

PS: Sorry for my english...

Comment: Does `id` without arguments show the necessary groups?

Comment: Hi grawity. No, id without arguments does not show. What I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have updated the user account (/etc/group), however, your *currently running* processes are not in the new group yet. This is because each process has its own credentials, including the secondary group list, which – for login sessions – is initialized once at login time and inherited by your processes.

(`id` shows the credentials its own process has, and `id username` reads from the account database.)

To solve your problem, log out, then log in again. You will have the new group in the list.

For a temporary fix, you could `su` or `sudo -s -u` to yourself.

Comment: Had a winscp session open before I added them to the secondary group and was really puzzled. Would have been puzzled for a lot longer if I hadn't seen this. Thanks!